# How to send data to email through contact form

Tags: html, html-email, contact-form

I'm trying to send a message to an email like in this code, once you click on "Enviar", your message goes to your email with the name, email and message info. I'm using this provider but it's not working: https://formsubmit.co/ this is the code:

````
      <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Contáctanos</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <form>
                <form action="https://formsubmit.co/myemaiL@gmail.com" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="Name">Nombre</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" placeholder="Name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="Email">Email</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email-1" placeholder="Email" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="Message">Mensaje</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" id="Message" placeholder="Ingresa tu mensaje" required></textarea>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Enviar</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>```

Hopefully someone can help me out, thanks!
````

Comment: Use [a validator](https://validator.nu/). You have an extra `<form>` in there.

Comment: Also, [read the instructions](https://formsubmit.co/). The service you are using only have three steps and you missed out step 2 entirely.

Comment: And your submit button needs to be inside the form; otherwise what are you submitting?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that submit button is outside `<form>` open and close tag. However the `<form` tag immediately after the modal-body class is not necessary

Your code should be like this

```
 <form action="https://formsubmit.co/laide_lawal@yahoo.com" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Name">Nombre</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" placeholder="Name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Email">Email</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email-1" placeholder="Email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Message">Mensaje</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" id="Message" placeholder="Ingresa tu mensaje" required></textarea>
            </div>
         
       
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```